# Firing an event every time eth gets deposited into a wallet

Tags: web3js

(I am using a private blockchain running on my computer for testing this)

So I am coding a simple front end app, that waits for a user to deposit some value of ETH into an address, before allowing the user to continue execution of the app.

I am wondering is there anyway to set an event listener on certain address, that gets fired every time a transaction is made to that address.

More importantly is it possible to do this without getting into using Contracts just vanilla wallets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any better way than polling. In web3.js 0.2.x, something like this should work (untested code):

```
function waitForBalance(account, amount, cb) {
  web3.eth.getBalance(account, function (err, balance) {
    if (balance >= amount) {
      cb();
    } else {
      // Try again in 1 second.
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        waitForBalance(account, amount, cb);
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
}

waitForBalance("0x123abc987...", web3.toWei(1, "ether"), function () {
  alert("1 ether received!");
});
```

Comment: This answer is good when sticking to simple wallets. 

But I realize it was fairly easy to deploy a Contract wallet, with custom event handling. This is the approach I ended up using. 

However thank you for your answer